# 403 Forbidden on when posting HTML chars after server move

Tags: html, http-post, character, http-status-code-403

The site I'm working on was working perfectly on a development server, however the client has his own server so I transferred the files + database, sorted file permissions etc.

Now everything on the site works fine however when I send certain HTML characters via post (from WYSIWYG or regular textfield) e.g. `<h1>` or `<ul>` I get a Forbidden 403 Error - You don't have permission to access [THE-REQUESTED-URI] on this server.

It's a LAMP Server, PHP 5.3

By the way Apache mod_security isn't running. What else could be causing the problem??

Also there is nothing in the servers error log about this.

Answer (score -2):

Add `enctype="text/plain"` to your form tag.
It might help.

Comment: Only "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and "multipart/form-data" are well supported. There is no (and by definition cannot be) a standard plain text serialisation of form data.